# Stripe::Customer.create not attaching the payment method to customer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

I am creating a setup intent and receiving the payment method's id from it. Then I am creating a customer using the following code

```
customer = Stripe::Customer.create({
      email: current_user.email,
      description: "Customer for subscription",
      payment_method: params[:payment_method]
    })
```

It is returning the following response

```
{
  "id": "cus_IZmhg4VhIwFUBI",
  "object": "customer",
  "address": null,
  "balance": 0,
  "created": 1608037176,
  "currency": null,
  "default_source": null,
  "delinquent": false,
  "description": "Customer for subscription",
  "discount": null,
  "email": "customer@example.com",
  "invoice_prefix": "76BF0C5E",
  "invoice_settings": {
    "custom_fields": null,
    "default_payment_method": null,
    "footer": null
  },
  "livemode": false,
  "metadata": {
  },
  "name": null,
  "next_invoice_sequence": 1,
  "phone": null,
  "preferred_locales": [

  ],
  "shipping": null,
  "tax_exempt": "none"
}
```

The problem is, it is not attaching the payment method to the customer, when I try to create a subscription using the customer object, it returns the following error:

**Stripe::InvalidRequestError (This customer has no attached payment source or default payment method.):**

But when I look in the dashboard, the payment method is already attached with the customer

Comment: What kind data are you passing in for the `payment_method`?

Comment: I am passing the payment id which I got from the setup intent. When I check the dashboard, the payment is already attached with the customer but somehow, when I pass customer id to the subscription, it returns that customer has no attached payment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `payment_method` is attached, and you can [list them for the customer](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/list). Then, you need to set explicitly the [`invoice_settings.default_payment_method`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/update#update_customer-invoice_settings-default_payment_method) for the Customer, which is what will be used for the subscription creation.

Comment: Not working either. When I list payment method for customers, it appears, but still getting the same error after explicitly setting the `invoice_settings.default_payment_method`... ```Stripe::InvalidRequestError (The customer does not have a payment method with the ID pm_1HyszfKNXDR22L81DER6eWTE. The payment method must be attached to the customer.):```

Comment: Yes, this would need to be attached first and then you can run the Customer update. As you found in your other answer you can also set this during customer creation: https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/create#create_customer-invoice_settings-default_payment_method

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by the @Nolan's answer, I have fixed the issue by passing payment id to `invoice_settings.default_payment_method` while customer creation. Following is the code snippet:

```
customer = Stripe::Customer.create({
      email: current_user.email,
      description: "Customer for subscription",
      payment_method: params[:payment_method],
      invoice_settings: {
        default_payment_method: params[:payment_method] 
      } 
    })
```

Comment: Glad you got it sorted out!